# react component's data state vs. props

Tags: reactjs

I know the main concern about when to put something on the state or receive as props, but what about when I have something that is suitable for both? I have items that should be 'active' when the parent is active(props) and also have the option to toggle this attribute from a click event(state).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is something like a `parentActive` variable held in the state of the parent and passed as a prop to the child(ren). Then a `childActive` variable held in the state of the child that is toggled by your click event. Then you'd simply have some logic / a conditional within the child that determines whether it's active. For example:

```
// Within child component
if (this.props.parentActive || this.state.childActive) { }
```

In general, when you have a new value that needs logic, you store it in state, create the click handlers that you need within that component, then pass it off (and possibly its click handler) as a prop for children. In your case, you need logic for a value/active flag within the parent, and logic for a value/active flag in the child.. so it sounds like you would want to set state in both of them, and pass the parent value as a prop for the child.

Comment: I would also add, that in general, you don't need the state of the parent. Let the parent handle its state and use the children props to update their UI.